# C# WCF Global Namespaces - Royal Mail

Tags: c#, soap

I've got a WCF SOAP client which is generating a request. This is being refused by the server as an invalid request. I've traced it down to namespaces using SOAPUI but cannot figure out how I can get the client to produce the required result.

The client was generated as a web service reference from the wsdl and is producing the following SOAP message;

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header></s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <createShipmentRequest xmlns="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/api/ship/V2">
      <integrationHeader>
        <dateTime xmlns="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/integration/core/V1">2015-07-23</dateTime>
        <version xmlns="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/integration/core/V1">2</version>
        <identification xmlns="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/integration/core/V1">
          <applicationId>some random number</applicationId>
          <transactionId>some reference number</transactionId>
        </identification>
      </integrationHeader>
    </createShipmentRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As you can see the namespaces are being outputted on the individual elements...

The working example I have has the namespaces defined in the SOAP Envelope;

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:v2="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/api/ship/V2" xmlns:v1="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/integration/core/V1" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header></s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <v2:createShipmentRequest>
      <v2:integrationHeader>
        <v1:dateTime>2015-07-23</v1:dateTime>
        <v1:version>2</v1:version>
        <v1:identification>
          <v1:applicationId>some random number</v1:applicationId>
          <v1:transactionId>some reference number</v1:transactionId>
        </v1:identification>
      </v2:integrationHeader>
    </v2:createShipmentRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

From what I understand this should not make a difference but the sever simply rejects the request. After modifying my generated request in SOAPUI it is defiantly this causing the problem, so how can I move the two namespace definitions v1 & v2 to the SOAP Envelope and then have the correct elements use the correct prefix?

My client is initiated using the following function;

```
private shippingAPIPortTypeClient GetProxy() {

  BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
  myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

  shippingClient = new shippingAPIPortTypeClient(myBinding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(shippingClientSandboxEndpoint), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("api.royalmail.com"), new AddressHeaderCollection()));
  shippingClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;

  return shippingClient;
}
```

Comment: I've just run in to EXACTLY the same maddening problem with Royal Mail. Wasted hours figuring out their service just doesn't respect XML standards. Thanks for posting your solution - I'll try it out.

Comment: where did you get the shippingAPIPortTypeClient?

Comment: @ReiA.Banaag The client is generated as a webservice reference using visual studio. You basically create a new web service and browse to the directory where you have the Royal Mail API WSDL file. Visual studio will then create you all the classes and a client. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx for a quick guide

Comment: @Ash I already added the service but the problem is shippingAPIPortType  or shippingAPIPortTypeClient part of the code is invalid. though if we check from the references I can find it from there but i cannot refer that code.

Comment: @ReiA.Banaag Probably worth opening a new question showing your full code. If you have the generated classes, then it sounds like your not including them in the class you wish to use them in.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So it turns out I needed to create a custom MessageFormatter and attach it as a behaviour to the client operations.

For anybody else needing to do this you need 3 files;

Firstly you create a custom message class which implements Message. Here in the OnWriteStartEnvelope method you add/define the namespaces you want in the Envelope.

```
class RoyalMailMessage: Message {
  private readonly Message message;

  public RoyalMailMessage(Message message) {
    this.message = message;
  }
  public override MessageHeaders Headers {
    get {
      return this.message.Headers;
    }
  }
  public override MessageProperties Properties {
    get {
      return this.message.Properties;
    }
  }
  public override MessageVersion Version {
    get {
      return this.message.Version;
    }
  }
  protected override void OnWriteStartBody(XmlDictionaryWriter writer) {
    writer.WriteStartElement("Body", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
  }
  protected override void OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer) {
    this.message.WriteBodyContents(writer);
  }
  protected override void OnWriteStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryWriter writer) {
    writer.WriteStartElement("s", "Envelope", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "v2", null, "http://www.royalmailgroup.com/api/ship/V2");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "v1", null, "http://www.royalmailgroup.com/integration/core/V1");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsd", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

  }
}
```

Then you create a custom Class which implements IClientMessageFormatter. This makes use of the Message class we defined above for outgoing requests made by the client;

```
public class RoyalMailMessageFormatter: IClientMessageFormatter {
  private readonly IClientMessageFormatter formatter;

  public RoyalMailMessageFormatter(IClientMessageFormatter formatter) {
    this.formatter = formatter;
  }

  public object DeserializeReply(Message message, object[] parameters) {
    return this.formatter.DeserializeReply(message, parameters);
  }

  public Message SerializeRequest(MessageVersion messageVersion, object[] parameters) {
    var message = this.formatter.SerializeRequest(messageVersion, parameters);
    return new RoyalMailMessage(message);
  }
}
```

We then need to create a custom class which implements IOperationBehavior. This is needed so we can attatch the custom message formatter to the service operations as a behaviour;

```
class RoyalMailIEndpointBehavior: IOperationBehavior {

  public RoyalMailIEndpointBehavior() {}

  public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription description, ClientOperation proxy) {
    IClientMessageFormatter currentFormatter = proxy.Formatter;
    proxy.Formatter = new RoyalMailMessageFormatter(currentFormatter);
  }

  public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) {

  }

  public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation) {

  }

  public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription) {

  }

}
```

Finally, we need to add the custom IOperation behaviour to all the service operations generated by WCF;

```
private shippingAPIPortTypeClient GetProxy() {

  BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
  myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

  shippingClient = new shippingAPIPortTypeClient(myBinding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(shippingClientSandboxEndpoint), EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("api.royalmail.com"), new AddressHeaderCollection()));
  shippingClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;

  foreach(OperationDescription od in shippingClient.Endpoint.Contract.Operations) {
    od.Behaviors.Add(new RoyalMailIEndpointBehavior());
  }
  return shippingClient;
}
```

The namespaces should now be in the SOAP Envelope and the elements all use the correct prefix giving us something like;

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v2="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/api/ship/V2" xmlns:v1="http://www.royalmailgroup.com/integration/core/V1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <s:Header></s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <v2:createShipmentRequest>
      <v2:integrationHeader>
        <v1:dateTime>2015-07-23T20:37:07.937+01:00</v1:dateTime>
        <v1:version>2</v1:version>
        <v1:identification>
          <v1:applicationId>SOME RANDOM ID</v1:applicationId>
          <v1:transactionId>SOME RANDOM ID</v1:transactionId>
        </v1:identification>
      </v2:integrationHeader>
    </v2:createShipmentRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: I know it says not to add comments that say "thanks" but in this case I feel it is warranted given the amount of people that find a solution to their problem and don't explain what it was, just leave a comment of "fixed it now", so thank you for coming back and providing a complete and working example to resolve the problem.