# WCF serialization issue on mono

Tags: wcf, mono

I'm using wcf for a web service. it works on .net framework 4.5. but it crashes on mono.

**Exception Details**
System.InvalidOperationException : There was an error generating the XML document.
----> System.ArgumentException : The empty string '' is not a valid local name.
at <0x00000 + 0x00000> 
at (wrapper remoting-invoke)

This exception was thrown in System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteBodyContents()
So I have overridden this method(similar as [Royal Mail Shipping API C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595770/c-sharp-wcf-royal-mail-soap-api-declare-namespace-in-header)) and got another exception.

**Exception Details**
Received an invalid SOAP Fault message
  ----> System.Xml.XmlException : Content cannot be converted to the type System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName. Line 1, position 116.
  ----> System.InvalidCastException : The String 'wsa:MessageAddressingHeaderRequired' cannot be represented as an XmlQualifiedName.  A namespace for prefix 'wsa' cannot be found.
  at <0x00000 + 0x00000> 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke)

Is there anyway to replace the default FaultMessage serializer on Mono?

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this exception when client and server were on different OS (linux server and windows client). My workaround was in using another serializer. I used Jil JSON and it worked OK.