# WCF Client Message Format c#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, client

I'm creating an application that consumes a WCF web service. When I test a certain operation in SOAP UI, it works, however, when I test in VS2017 console app, I receive an error:

"The content type text/html;charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding"

I used Fiddler to grab the request from my console app, and I've narrowed the issue down to some of the formatting in the SOAP request. When I format my console app request to match the request Fiddler generates, it works. There are prefixes that are defaulted in my request that seem to be causing the issue, as well as xmlns declarations. I need to know how I can modify these parts of the request to conform to the web service which I have absolutely no control over (major corporation).

The prefixes `s` and `h` need to change to different values. I took this request and put it into SOAP UI, swapped the `s` and `h` throughout to match how Fiddler is passing in the request, and it works. I also had to move xmlns:h up to the Envelope level. Is there something I can change in my config file? Is there something with Message Contracting that I can easily implement? I need to be able to format this correctly, but I'm not sure what the best way would be.

BAD:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:FooListHeader xmlns:h="http://foo.foo.com/Hello" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <h:FooList>
        <h:FooStatement>
          <h:Title>Foo</h:Title>
          <h:Value>123</h:Value>
        </h:FooStatement>
      </h:FooList>
    </h:FooListHeader>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetFooRequestType xmlns="http://foo.foo.com/Hello">
      <MessageRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ConFooRequest/>
      </MessageRequest>
    </GetFooRequestType>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

GOOD (how can I convert above bad example to this good example below in my app?):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:foo="http://foo.foo.com/Hello">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <foo:FooListHeader xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <foo:FooList>
        <foo:FooStatement>
          <foo:Title>Foo</foo:Title>
          <foo:Value>123</foo:Value>
        </foo:FooStatement>
      </foo:FooList>
    </foo:FooListHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <foo:GetFooRequestType xmlns="http://foo.foo.com/Hello">
      <foo:MessageRequest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <foo:ConFooRequest/>
      </foo:MessageRequest>
    </foo:GetFooRequestType>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

[Service Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkjMA.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="foo" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://Foo.foo.com/foo/foows.svc"       
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="foo"
          contract="Service1Reference.IFooServices" name="foo" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Everything I can find on the internet about this topic mostly revolves around the service side of things, not the client side.

The company has provided me with a .wsdl file and an XML reference file. I'm not quite sure what to do with the reference file, but I have loaded the .wsdl file directly under "Add Service Reference" in my application. I could not discover the service using the endpoint like I have in previous projects that I have worked on, so I had to store the file locally on my PC and specify the path to it directly when I added the service reference. Again, I am not able to discover the service using the typical ?wsdl address most likely due to service config settings for security purposes. Thanks so much for any responses!

Comment: Anyone? I found the following, and I plan on directly modifying the request before it is sent out to the server, unless there is a better way.               var serxml = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(client.GetType());
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            serxml.Serialize(ms, client);
            string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());

Comment: I have a similar (if not identical) issue. How did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Maybe this SO can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595770/c-sharp-wcf-global-namespaces-royal-mail/31597758#31597758